# Hadwiger number in vertex collapse in a bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, graph-minors

If $G=(V,E)$ is a finite graph, let the *Hadwiger number* $\eta(G)$ equal the largest integer $n$ such that the complete graph $K_n$ is a [minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_minor) of $G$.

Is there a bipartite graph $G$ on more than $3$ vertices such that whenever $2$ non-adjacent vertices are collapsed, then the Hadwiger number increases?